# How can I confirm that FireFox is using the debug version of Flash Player?

Tags: debugging, firefox, flash

I know I can look at plugins and their version under Firefox, but how can I tell if I'm running the debug version of the Flash Player?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right-click the Flash, if you see "Debugger" in the context menu, you're using the debug version.

Comment: I see the debugger option, but according to the page thirtydot linked I am not running the debug player.

Comment: @James McMahon - Unless you're using a different browser, you've got a very strange problem. Even Adobe support will tell you to view the context menu.

Comment: My bad, I switch between Chrome and Firefox so much I don't even think about it anymore. Great Answer.

Comment: Is there a way to find a proper setup file for flash debugger version, Even after I install one, it doesn't show up.

Comment: @e10 which browser? If Chrome, you have to disable pepper.

Comment: turned out this was due to windows 8, that it doesn't show me any Flash Debugger.. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is also one more option to get version of your flash player http://playerversion.com/